# Qt QScrollArea's margins doesn't affect scroll bar size

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, scrollbar

When I place some widget in `QScrollBar`'s area margin, I would expect that scroll bars inside it would not appear in those margins, but it does. Here is MWE code:

```
class MyWidget : public QScrollArea
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyWidget(QWidget *parent)
        : QScrollArea(parent)
    {
        _bottomWidget = new QWidget{this};
        _bottomWidget->setStyleSheet("background-color: red");

        auto contentWidget = new QWidget{this};
        contentWidget->setFixedSize(200, 1500);
        contentWidget->setStyleSheet("background-color: blue");
        setWidget(contentWidget);
    }

protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* e) override
    {
        QScrollArea::resizeEvent(e);
        QRect cr = contentsRect();
        setViewportMargins(0, 0, 0, 100);
        _bottomWidget->setGeometry(QRect(cr.left(), cr.bottom() - 100, cr.width(), 100));
    }
private:
    QWidget* _bottomWidget;
};
```

The result is following:
[image]

I added some colors to widgets just to see result: blue widget is a very high widget just to make `QScrollBar` visible on the left, and red widget is a widget put inside the `QScrollArea`'s margin. In otherwords I want the `QScrollBar` to ends where red widget begins. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want the red widget to always be visible?

Comment: @eyllanesc Doesn't matter

Comment: Is that the QScrollbar is based on the viewport of the QScrollArea, and the margins are part of the viewport, therefore observe that behavior. So a possible solution is not to use the margins and create a QVBoxLayout where the QScrollArea is at the top and another QWidget at the bottom with a fixed height.

Comment: @eyllanesc can I put a widget inside `QScrollBar`'s margin instead of its viewport's margin? I am willing to make the whole widget to be a class derived from `QScrollArea`.